# Longtable with multicolumn

Tags: tables, longtable

[image: Longtable-Finale]
I'm trying to make a table like the one above

```
\begin{longtable}{llll}
\caption{Eine Tabelle in Überlänge.} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}}\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}}\\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
\end{longtable}
```

[image: Result]

Now i have massive Problems with the last Part (Umsätze in EUR).
Can someone help me please?

Comment: see my "edit 2"

Answer (score 2):

The following input is the same as your own, but it uses the `booktabs` package and includes the "Umsätze in EUR" part. `midrule`, `toprule` and `bottomrule` are booktabs variants of `hline` with better spacing. `cmidrule` is booktabs' `cline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % make sure to add this line to your own document

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{llll}
    \caption{Eine Tabelle in Überlänge.} \label{tab:long} \\

    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Umsätze in EUR}\\ % this the key addition
    \cmidrule{3-4} % the underline of Umsätze...
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}}\\ 
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{4}{c}
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule 
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Umsätze in EUR}\\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}}\\ 
    \midrule
    \endhead

    \midrule
     \multicolumn{4}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
     \midrule
    \endfoot

    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO \\ 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The top of the outputted table looks like:

[image]

Edit: if you want to add a third column under "Umsätze in EUR", you need to change

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Umsätze in EUR}\\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
```

to

```
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Umsätze in EUR}\\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
```

i.e. 2 --> 3 and 3-4 --> 3-5, in both locations.

edit 2:

This should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in]{geometry} % this makes the left and right margins 1 inch/ 2.54cm; change it if you want to keep your preferred margins.

\begin{document}

\normalsize % change this to \small if you can't fit the table in the page width
\begin{longtable}{lllllll}
    \caption{Eine Tabelle in Überlänge.} \label{tab:long} \\

    \toprule
    & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Umsätze in EUR}\\ % this the key addition
    \cmidrule{5-7} % the underline of Umsätze...
    Firma & Ort & PLZ & Straße & 2013 & 2014 & 2015\\ % I got rid of the \multicolumns, as they were affecting alignment
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{7}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule 
    & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Umsätze in EUR}\\
    \cmidrule{5-7}
    \textbf{First column} & \textbf{Second column} & \textbf{Third column} & \textbf{Third column} & 2013 & 2014 & 2015\\ 
    \midrule
    \endhead

    \midrule
    \multicolumn{7}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
    \midrule
    \endfoot

    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO & aaaaa & bbbbb & ccccc \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO & aaaaa & bbbbb & ccccc \\
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & HALLO & aaaaa & bbbbb & ccccc \\
\end{longtable}
\normalsize % return text to normal size


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

- your question is not very clear
- page layout of your document is unknown (how wide can table be?)
- in MWE (Minimal Working Example) you provide a dummy data, which apparently not mimic real data (regarding their lenght), so it is hard to help you in table design
- regarding problem with multi column cells, @Patrick Ferguson solve your problem in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547120/longtable-with-multicolumn/547125#547125) (+1)
- it is not clear, why you have different column headers in the first part of your table and at other parts
- for numbers in last three columns is sensible to use `S` column type defined in the `siunitx` package: wit it numbers are aligned at decimal coma

One solution for your table, based on retyping showed desired table lookout in the first image in your question), can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text filler

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-4]
\begingroup
\small
\sisetup{table-format=6.2,
         output-decimal-marker={,}
         }
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{} llll SSS @{}}
\caption{Eine Tabelle in Überlänge.}
\label{tab:long} \\
    \toprule
    & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Umsätze in EUR}}  \\ % this the key addition
    \cmidrule{5-7} % the underline of Umsätze...
\thead{Firma} 
    & \thead{Ort} 
        & \thead{PLZ} 
            & \thead{Straße} 
                & {\thead{2013}} 
                    & {\thead{2014}} 
                        & {\thead{2015}}    \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{ -- continued from previous page}            \\
    \toprule
    & & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Umsätze in EUR}}  \\ % this the key addition
    \cmidrule{5-7} % the underline of Umsätze...
\thead{Firma}
    & \thead{Ort}
        & \thead{PLZ}
            & \thead{Straße}
                & {\thead{2013}}
                    & {\thead{2014}}
                        & {\thead{2015}}    \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape{Continued on next page}}   \\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
%%%% Table body
Donau Buroeinrichtunegen
    & Linz      & 4020  & Schubertplatz 9
        & 51560,00  & 56716,00  & 62387,00  \\
Burocenter Tirol
    & Innsbruck & 6020  & Innstrase 234
        & 480536,00   & 528589,00 & 581448,56 \\ 
Carynthia Firmenauststatittung 
    & Klagenfurt    & 9219 & Kaiser-Frantz.Str. 1806 
        & 199120,00 & 219032,00 & 240935,20 \\
    \addlinespace
Donau Buroeinrichtunegen
    & Linz      & 4020  & Schubertplatz 9
        & 51560,00  & 56716,00  & 62387,00  \\
Burocenter Tirol
    & Innsbruck & 6020  & Innstrase 234
        & 480536,00   & 528589,00 & 581448,56 \\
Carynthia Firmenauststatittung
    & Klagenfurt    & 9219 & Kaiser-Frantz.Str. 1806
        & 199120,00 & 219032,00 & 240935,20 \\
    \addlinespace
Donau Buroeinrichtunegen
    & Linz      & 4020  & Schubertplatz 9
        & 51560,00  & 56716,00  & 62387,00  \\
Burocenter Tirol
    & Innsbruck & 6020  & Innstrase 234
        & 480536,00   & 528589,00 & 581448,56 \\
Carynthia Firmenauststatittung
    & Klagenfurt    & 9219 & Kaiser-Frantz.Str. 1806
        & 199120,00 & 219032,00 & 240935,20 \\
    \addlinespace
Donau Buroeinrichtunegen
    & Linz      & 4020  & Schubertplatz 9
        & 51560,00  & 56716,00  & 62387,00  \\
Burocenter Tirol
    & Innsbruck & 6020  & Innstrase 234
        & 480536,00   & 528589,00 & 581448,56 \\
Carynthia Firmenauststatittung
    & Klagenfurt    & 9219 & Kaiser-Frantz.Str. 1806
        & 199120,00 & 219032,00 & 240935,20 \\
    \addlinespace
Donau Buroeinrichtunegen
    & Linz      & 4020  & Schubertplatz 9
        & 51560,00  & 56716,00  & 62387,00  \\
Burocenter Tirol
    & Innsbruck & 6020  & Innstrase 234
        & 480536,00   & 528589,00 & 581448,56 \\
Carynthia Firmenauststatittung
    & Klagenfurt    & 9219 & Kaiser-Frantz.Str. 1806
        & 199120,00 & 219032,00 & 240935,20 \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
\lipsum{6}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your real table is wider than table above, than is sensible to consider to write some cells contents (for example in the first column and maybe in the fourth too) in two lines. IN this can be of help `xltabular` package, which is combination of the `longtable` and `tabularx` package.